# Selenium Firefox-Unable to locate an Web Element. Works on chrome and edge

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I have a piece of code that works on Chrome and Edge but failing in Firefox browser. The page gets loaded but unable to identify a web element. Is there any step I should follow(like profile settings) while initializing the geckodriver? Need help in identifying the problem:

Code-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","<path>\geckodriver.exe");
private static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I tried locating the web element on firefox and its found on DOM. I have used `implicitwait()`. The page gets loaded and element visible. But somehow Firefox driver is not able to identify the element.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, single backslashes (`\`) are escape characters, so you need to use either double backslashes or a forward slash in the path.

Change your code as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","<path>\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I replaced the backslash with double backslash and also added firefoxprofile+options and it worked. Got a new problem though. Thank you though!